# How can I get use data from a useEffect and push it to my child component without it being null? (Conditional rendering seems to not work also.)

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, react-props

My App component passes the urlList to the Player component once it loads. The problem comes in my Player component. I am trying to use  props.urlList for something other than a console log (which works great haha) so that I can play the urls in my application

App.js

```
  useEffect( () => {
    setUrlList(() => {
    if (!email) return;
    console.log("triggering use effect!")
    async function fetchUrlList(){
  //api code here but is too long to write.
      }
      setUrlList(result) // this works fine!
      console.log(urlList) // this logs it fine!
   return urlList
    }
    fetchUrlList()
      return
  }) },[email]);
```

```
      <Player
          currentSongIndex={currentSongIndex}
          setCurrentSongIndex={setCurrentSongIndex}
          nextSongIndex={nextSongIndex}
          songs={urlList} // when trying to render this component, it throws an error in the as null or undefined 
      />
```

Player.js

```
function Player(props) {          
return(
<audio
              src={props.songs[props.currentSongIndex].src}. // error is cannot read property of           null (songs)
              ref={audioElement}
          ></audio>)}
           export default Player;
```

I tried putting the Player component in a conditional render but it still does not work.

Comment: What's the initial value of the `urlList`? If the data type of `songs` prop is array, you can initialize the value of `urlList` state to empty array `const [urlList, setUrlList] = useState([])`

Comment: `useEffect` runs *after* a component has rendered ... so your `Player` will be rendered first with the initial value of `songs` (presumably null), then the effect runs (updating `songs`) which, if the value of `songs` has changed since the last render, will cause a re-render of `Player`.

Comment: @StevenFrew you're exactly right. However the Player component is not rendering at all, in fact nothing is when I load the component because that songs value is null and has not yet fetched the data